# Redirect members to custom page upon logging in through WP admin

Tags: customization, wp-admin, redirect

When a members logs in through WP admin, I would like to redirect them instantly to a custom URL. What will I need to change to make this possible? Respond with step-by-step details would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/)  It works dandy for setting different redirects for each role and even user capabilities.

Comment: Cheers Brian...